Android webview, access website's cached images
Can I access the actual images (file or data URI) that a webview caches when loading a webpage? And, if so, can I find the file associated with a particular URL link?
For example, I want the cached file associated with the image URL cdn.example.com/my_picture.jpg that was just loaded on the website www.example.com/stars/.
The webview uses cached resources when making requests to the same image URLs so the information exists, but can I access it?
I know I can get to a cache like this:
File dir = new File(getContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
if (dir.exists()) {
    for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {
        String filename = f.getName();
    }
}

But it's not clear that this is the right place. It's a lot of folders within folders, etc. I also used Device File Explorer in Android Studio to look around in the directory.
I already saw this answer; that's how I got the cache directory in the above code. But then what?
